# sshpass with proxycommand returns without running anything

Tags: ssh, proxy, sshpass

In our environments, we have several servers in production. Every time I want to search for something, it may be in 1 of 4 different servers.
I am creating a script to automate this search, so that I directly know which server is involved.

I am connecting through a jumphost.

So far the following command works fine :

```bash
$ ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jumphost" user@server "ls"
```

Now, because I have to run this several times, I am searching for a way to only have to use the password once.

**Both the jumphost and the server require the same password, and public keys are not an option (not allowed, I literally cannot do it).**

I have been reading about **sshpass** for this and am trying this :

```bash
$ sshpass -p password ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jumphost" user@server "ls"
```

(I know -p is not safe and will use -e of -f as soon as I am successful with this step).

When I do this, I can login in both systems but the command returns before I see the result of ls.
I have tried to have the **-t** option to ssh without any success.

I have also tried the **-J** option from ssh, with the same results (command returns without returning any results).

```bash
$ sshpass -p password ssh -J user@jumphost user@server "ls"
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Solution was to use sshpass twice :

```bash
$ sshpass -p password_server ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -p password_jumphost ssh -W %h:%p user@jumphost" user@server "ls"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running ssh in verbose mode:

`ssh -vvv -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jumphost" user@server "ls"`

I'm sure it will show something of interest. A hook with which you can figure this out.

Comment: That did the trick! With the verbose flag I realized that I had to use sshpass twice. I added the solution in the question. Thanks!